# Set child folder type in registry/desktop.ini

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, user-folders, desktop.ini

I disabled automatic folder type discovery with Winaero Tweaker, but that just sets all folders to General items (it creates `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell` and sets it to `NotSpecified`), which prevents Windows from saving custom folder types.

Is there a way to set folder types (Music, Pictures, etc., including childs) to their appropriate file types, while still preventing Windows from setting or changing it by itself, by setting all other folders as `NotSpecified`?

Script output:

```
{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7} Generic
{7D49D726-3C21-4F05-99AA-FDC2C9474656} Documents
{B3690E58-E961-423B-B687-386EBFD83239} Pictures
{94D6DDCC-4A68-4175-A374-BD584A510B78} Music
{5FA96407-7E77-483C-AC93-691D05850DE8} Videos
{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259} Downloads
{C4D98F09-6124-4FE0-9942-826416082DA9} UsersLibraries
{FBB3477E-C9E4-4B3B-A2BA-D3F5D3CD46F9} Documents.Library
{0B2BAAEB-0042-4DCA-AA4D-3EE8648D03E5} Pictures.Library
{3F2A72A7-99FA-4DDB-A5A8-C604EDF61D6B} Music.Library
{5F4EAB9A-6833-4F61-899D-31CF46979D49} Generic.Library
{631958A6-AD0F-4035-A745-28AC066DC6ED} Videos.Library
{3F98A740-839C-4AF7-8C36-5BADFB33D5FD} Documents.LibraryFolder
{24CCB8A6-C45A-477D-B940-3382B9225668} HomeFolder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done via the registry. Most file folders have a **Customize** tab in their **Properties** dialog, where you can specify/override the default/sniffed *FolderType*. Beneath the type selector, there's a checkbox labeled: `Also apply this template to all subfolders`.

[image]

When this option is checked, the selected *FolderType* is applied to both existing subfolders & any new subfolders.
The underlying method is the creation of a subkey of the folder's *Bag* (saved view) named `Inherit`. This key contains a single *REG_SZ* value named **FolderType** containg the string identifier of the *FolderType*.

[image]

When a folder doesn't have a saved view (newly-created or never viewed), **Explorer** queries the saved views of the folder's parent & its ancestors to see if inheritance was specifed. ***If found, this value takes precedence over content-sniffing***.

### And here's the nifty part!

Even though the UI has no option to specify inheritance for drives, **This PC**, and the *rooted/virtaul Desktop*, if an `Inherit` subkey is added to heir *Bag*, it will affect nearly all subfolders.
The rooted Desktop is the one seen when you select **Desktop** fron the leftmost drop-arrow in the **Explorer** Address bar.

[image]

To locate its *Bag*, check the value of `NodeSlot` in `BagMRU`:

[image]

So I want to create an `Inherit` subkey for Bag #3:

[image]

This imposes the `Generic` (NotSpecifed) FolderType on any folder that doesn't have another type spedifed. The various folders under **This PC** can specify their associated type & set inheritance to override this global default.

---

### Troubleshooting code

Get the number of saved views. If you've hit 5000, that's the limit & things will be weird --- BagMRU & Bags *must* be deleted.

```
((gp "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count
```

What *FolderTypes* have custom templates set via **Apply to Folders**:

```
$Defaults = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults'
$FT       = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
(gi $defaults).Property |
 Select @{N = 'ID'; E = {$_}},
        @{N = 'Name'; E = {(gp "$FT\$_").CanonicalName}}
```

This will list the *FolderTypes* currently applied to one or more saved views. Curious to see if any of your folders are using the `Music` template:

```
$source = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\'
$Lookup = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
gci $source -recurse | ? PSChildName -like '{*}' |
    select -Expand PSChildName -Unique | ForEach{ 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'ID' = $_
            'Name' = (gp "$Lookup\$_").CanonicalName
        }
}
```

Let's find out what bags are using the **Music** template:

```
$BagMRU = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU'
$Bags   = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
gci $bags -recurse |
 ? PSChildName -like '{94D6DDCC-4A68-4175-A374-BD584A510B78}' | ForEach{
    $Bag = $_.Name.Split('\')[-3]
    gci $BagMRU -recurse | ? { $_.GetValue('NodeSlot') -like $Bag } | ForEach{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
           'Bag'     = $Bag
           'MRUPath' = ($_.PSPath -split 'BagMRU')[-1]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolute awesome answer, thanks a lot.
Btw, can this be applied to my phone's folders in Explorer, as well? For some reason, it gets all it's folders set to Music, with no way to change it through Explorer..

Comment: A Samsung phone connected to Windows, under This PC.

Comment: I do want to try some interactive trouble-shooting, but have to deal with some other things right now. Not sure of your proficiency/1comfort level, but if this makes sense, go ahead & try: Backup BagMRU & Bags keys by right-click > Export. Delete the keys, sign out, siggn back in. Open Explorer, navgate up to the rooted Desktop, and close Exploer. Then open regedit & navigate to the keys. You should have just two bags. Perform the Inherit edit and see how the folders behave. You have the keys backed up to restore if need be,

Comment: I get you. It's just I have no clue as to the current state of those keys as well as possible interaction with templates created by **Apply to Folders**. I'm going to edit my answer to add some PowerShell code to gather some info. Stay tuned. But if you're comfortable with what I suggested, give it a try. Remember, previously saved views take precedence over Inherit.

Comment: Troubleshooting code added. Will add more but good start.

Comment: Appreciate your help very much, and in fact just went ahead and did it anyway, so I was able to identify the Bags for each of my folders, the Phone's folders', Drives, Desktop, etc., and set everything as intended, including inheritance, also set it for AllFolders. Rbooted, and everything is fine,... but for the phone folders; for whatever reason, they're just stuck as Music type.

Comment: Number is 42; second script ends in error: HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults doesn't exist. Anyway now it all boils down to where/why the phone folders get this particular folder type assigned and how to fix.

Comment: The error is normal if you haven't used **Apply to Folders** at any time. But if you're one of many annoyed by **Downloads** grouping by date, turn off grouping in your **Explorer** view & execute **Apply to Folders** _before_ accessing **Downloads** from any dialog.

Comment: And when you right-click in the _background_ of those phone folders, you don't have the `Customize this folder...` opton? Also, what are the GUID subkey names of the bags you think are the phone bags?

Comment: I'm actually (oddly?) very ok with that; in fact I used to do it on my own everytime, which was very annoying. Phone folders only have the General property tab; Phone GUID is {5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}, same for all: phone, int. and ext. sdcard. Btw, this is a fresh install of build 2004 (currently 19041.264), which I'm still setting up, so no extra luggage or leftovers.

Comment: That's truly bizarre, because `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}` _is_ the **Generic** _FolderType_!

Comment: I'm going to delete some of my earlier comments because the site is bugging me to move to chat. But I'm visually impaired & chat page doesn't play well with browser zooming. Try opening a normal folder using the Generic type, set the columns to your liking, then execute **Apply to Folders** . That may help.

Comment: Did that on an actual Generic folder (Downloads seems to be a special folder, though it's default content type is Generic) and run your script again, which now lists Generic, but still no dice, on the Phone folders.

Comment: Your last script throws an error: "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'HKCR' does not exist." But the only Music type folders set under 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' are my music folders, which I've set manually.

Comment: Whoops! Will ifx!

Comment: It would be better to edit your question to add this info in a code block.

Comment: Hi, you seem to know about the **Bag** an **BagMRU** Registry enrties more than anyone else I've found on the internet. After I've set a custom icon for a few folders all folder views were changing. I was applying folder view options trying to revert their appearance until I realized the problem was caused by custom icons. Now the problem is - automatic folder's type discovey doesn't work anymore, every new folder has a list view regardless of the content and **the only** way to force folder type discovery is to delete it's Bag entry (I am using ShellBagsView for finding the entries).

Comment: @Chupo_cro: If I'm reading your description properly -- Weird! And sounds mysterious enough that it's best suited to its own question; then you could post  specific paths, details of how you're applying cusotm icons, regsitry exports, etc. Have you tried exporting **`BagMRU`** and **`BagMRU`** ( so you can restore if desired) and then deleting them & restarting? Also, though I don't think it affects custom icons, search the **`Bags`** hierarchy for subkeys named `"Inherit"`

Comment: I did export **BagMRU** and **Bag** keys and then deleted them (# of saved views was 5000) and after that everything is working as it should. I noticed `Inherit` subkeys but it was impossible to repair such a large ammount of keys wihtout deleting them. Seems to me the problem is it is not possible to apply a custom icon without affecting `Optimize this folder for` setting - by clicking `Apply` after changing the icon the `Optimize this folder for` is applied too and that ruins everything. Seems as there isn't a way to reset the behavior without deleting the **BagMRU** and **Bag** keys.

Comment: Well, your problem was most likely not the `Inherit` keys, but that you'd hit the max for saved views. I see no odd behavior when I set the FolderType and a custom icon at the same time. The desktop.ini file is created with both the type & icon specified.