# Shell Bags Registry Hacks

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, windows-11

Windows often decides for itself against the will of the user how a folder should be presented. Despite the various "official" methods to ensure Windows displays folders *exactly* as the user wishes, I found they often revert. Therefore, I am now attempting the registry route.

I am looking to set the (default) folder view for ALL folders (regardless of type):

1. Set the view to details (especially for media files/folders i.e., `Music`, `Pictures`, and `Videos`, I still want those to display like any other files/folders, i.e. the columns `Name, Date modified, Type, Size`)
2. Set the group by to none (`Downloads` folder will by default group by date)
3. Set the sort by to name (again, `Downloads` will sort by date)
4. Set the sort by order to ascending (`Downloads` will sort by newest file, IIRC that's descending)
5. Disable the automatic folder type deduction, (could potentially break everything I've set)

I've tried following:

1. [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/1677995/what-registry-key-do-i-need-to-change-to-remove-group-by-downloads-folder-sear) which disables the `Downloads` folder group by
2. [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/1552438/set-child-folder-type-in-registry-desktop-ini) which tells me which folder IDs to put in the shell bags all folders registry key to set their defaults
3. [This post](https://winaero.com/reset-folder-view-folders-windows-10/) which tells me how to reset the folder view settings

I've also tried copying registry keys that seem relevant from places that seem to have the settings I want to the relevant folder IDs' registry keys:

[image: registry keys]

[image: sort binary key]

After all that effort and rebooting multiple times however, I found that the `Downloads` folder view is still wrong - it still sorts by date descending.

What could be the missing piece from my hack?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/DGxNguiK) is a dump of the registry keys I set:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell]
"BagMRU Size"=dword:00002710
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders]
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{0B2BAAEB-0042-4DCA-AA4D-3EE8648D03E5}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3F2A72A7-99FA-4DDB-A5A8-C604EDF61D6B}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3F98A740-839C-4AF7-8C36-5BADFB33D5FD}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5F4EAB9A-6833-4F61-899D-31CF46979D49}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5FA96407-7E77-483C-AC93-691D05850DE8}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{631958A6-AD0F-4035-A745-28AC066DC6ED}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7D49D726-3C21-4F05-99AA-FDC2C9474656}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:80,a1,a0,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,50,a4,9e,d0,6e,02,\
  00,00,e0,53,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:80,a1,a0,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,50,a4,9e,d0,6e,02,\
  00,00,e0,53,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{94D6DDCC-4A68-4175-A374-BD584A510B78}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:80,a1,a0,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,50,a4,9e,d0,6e,02,\
  00,00,e0,53,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{B3690E58-E961-423B-B687-386EBFD83239}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:80,a1,a0,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,50,a4,9e,d0,6e,02,\
  00,00,e0,53,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{C4D98F09-6124-4FE0-9942-826416082DA9}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:80,a1,a0,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,50,a4,9e,d0,6e,02,\
  00,00,e0,53,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{FBB3477E-C9E4-4B3B-A2BA-D3F5D3CD46F9}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:80,a1,a0,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,50,a4,9e,d0,6e,02,\
  00,00,e0,53,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders]
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{0B2BAAEB-0042-4DCA-AA4D-3EE8648D03E5}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3F2A72A7-99FA-4DDB-A5A8-C604EDF61D6B}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3F98A740-839C-4AF7-8C36-5BADFB33D5FD}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5F4EAB9A-6833-4F61-899D-31CF46979D49}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5FA96407-7E77-483C-AC93-691D05850DE8}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{631958A6-AD0F-4035-A745-28AC066DC6ED}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7D49D726-3C21-4F05-99AA-FDC2C9474656}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{94D6DDCC-4A68-4175-A374-BD584A510B78}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{B3690E58-E961-423B-B687-386EBFD83239}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{C4D98F09-6124-4FE0-9942-826416082DA9}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{FBB3477E-C9E4-4B3B-A2BA-D3F5D3CD46F9}]
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000000
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"Sort"=hex:a0,56,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,60,cd,97,d0,6e,02,00,00,30,00,31,00,20,00,\
  28,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,32,00,36,00,31,00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Show all registry keys and values you have set based on the linked posts. Show everything as text, if possible, instead of screenshots. You can use `regedit` to export the affected registry keys to a text file.

Comment: Hello from the author of two of your linked answers. First off, let me say that I haven't upgraded to Win11 yet, so not sure if there is now additional code that may fight with your prefferred defaults. Also, please clarify what mods are currently in effect -- `AllFolders` entries? `Inherit` entries? Mods to `FolderTypes`? Also, is `Downloads` the only folder still giving you grief?

Comment: @Bodo I've updated the post with a dump of the registry keys I set

Comment: @KeithMiller Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "mods currently in effect". I've updated the post with a dump of the registry keys I set. As for symptoms I'm seeing, indeed everything is in place except for the `Downloads` folder. I've fixed it by setting it up manually, but it would be nice to have documentation regarding how to set up an "all details" view, as I'm sure I'm not the only one who prefers to see everything in such view.

Comment: OKay, on first look at your registry dump, one thing that stands out is the `Sort` values don't look right to me. At least in Win10, the structure begns with 16 zero-valued bytes (`00`), a DWORD (4 bytes) specifying the number of `PropertyKey` structures follow, and then 20 bytes for each `PropertyKey` structure -- the final four bytes of each of these is always `01 00 00 00` (ascending) or `FF FF FF FF` (descending). Where did the values you have come from?

Comment: @KeithMiller I copied them from a different key that I thought had the settings I wanted. Maybe I copied them wrong somehow (even with a copy and paste), or the values are somehow corrupted (not sure how though), or the structure has changed for Win11 (I don't think that would change unless some feature related to explorer sort was added/changed).

Comment: OKay, just curous. I also doubt a low-level structure like that would have been changed. I imagine if you check some of your existing bags, the `Sort` values will have the leading zero bytes I mentioned earlier. I'm starting to compose an answer that I hope will provide the results you desire. I usually provide both "manual" instructions as well as **PowerShell** code options for modifications. Are you comfortable with **PowerShell** -- at least to the point of cutting, pasting, and executing code?

Comment: @KeithMiller It's been a while since this question was posted (and I performed the registry hacks), and [here's](https://pastebin.com/uErSYfe8) what's in bag 1's `Sort` key for me right now - it seems to be mostly zeros. As for executing random powershell code on the internet, I guess it helps if i can understand what's going on - usually by comparing my understanding of the code vs how it would go manually, so the addition of manual instructions would go a long way to ease my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements listed in the question are all handled by the app [**WinSetView**](https://lesferch.github.io/WinSetView). It's a free, open source, portable app that works by setting/clearing the same registry keys/values as outlined in Keith Miller's answer.

[image]

Comment: Cool project :) It seems to have done its magic for me, but I'll have to see if it persists reboots (I do those very rarely, only for windows updates) and handles various edge cases. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the upvote. The settings will definitely persist through reboots and Windows updates.

Answer (score 2):

First, for the sake of understanding the interplay of various settings, a few comments on the registry keys you have in your export:

- If you set any machine-wide defaults via `HKLM\...\AllFolders`, there is no need for duplicate entries under `HKCU\...\AllFolders`. You would only need them if you wanted to override some aspect of the machine-wide settings.
- The presence of the `"FolderType"="NotSpecified"` value under `[HKCU|HKLM]\...AllFolders` would override [content-sniffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing) to determine the initial view of a folder, so custom defaults for FolderTypes like `Music`, `Pictures`, and `Video` would only be applied when a folder's view is modified via the `Customize` tab in the `Properties` dialog.

I personally don't care for trying to force the `Generic` template on all folders; it seems a bit heavy-handed. Instead, for a similar result, I prefer customizing the defaults for other FolderTypes to replicate the settings of the `Generic` type.

I also don't like using `AllFolders` to customize any type that can also be customized via `Apply to Folders` for several reasons:

- If a FolderType implements `Apply to Folders`, an `AllFolders` seeting for the same type will cause the `Apply to Folders` settings  to be ignored, even if `Apply to Folders` is set afterward. This can be confusing.
- `Apply to Folders` customizations are easily modified via the UI -- not so with `AllFolders`.
- `Apply to Folders` customizations survive the deletion of `Bags` and `BagMRU` registry keys.

I think `AllFolders` entries are best reserved to modify `SearchResults` defaults, and if desired, setting common dialog defaults that differ from the **Explorer** defaults for a given type.

So, with all that in mind, take a deep breath, be resigned to a couple of restarts, and begin.

1. Delete existing saved views and customizations by deleting the following registry keys:

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
   HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
   HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
   ```

   - Under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`, delete all subkeys except `1` (holds Desktop layout).
   - Under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams`, delete the `Defaults` subkey along with any numbered subkeys, leaving only the `Desktop` subkey.

     **PowerShell** (Admin/Elevated) :

     ```
       -split @'
       HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
       HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
       HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
       HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
       '@ | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

       Get-ChildItem HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags | where PSChildName -ne 1 | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
       Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams | where PSChildName -ne Desktop | Remove-Item -Force
     ```
2. Restart
3. Set the `Generic` custom template:
   a. Open **Explorer** to the`This PC\Desktop` folder (or any other folder that defaults to the `Generic` template).
   b. Make all desired modifications to the view.
   c. `View` ribbon -> `Options` -> `Change folder and search options` -> `View` tab -> `Apply to Folders` -> accept confirmations.
4. Set the `OneDriveGeneric` custom template:
   a. Open **Explorer** to the`OneDrive` folder.
   b. Make all desired modifications to the view.
   c. `View` ribbon -> `Options` -> `Change folder and search options` -> `View` tab -> `Apply to Folders` -> accept confirmations.
5. In regedit, verify that values named:

   - `{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}` (Generic)
   - `{4F01EBC5-2385-41f2-A28E-2C5C91FB56E0}` (OneDriveGeneric)

   have been cfeated under:

   - `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults`

Now, we want to create copies of these values that differ only in name. You want to copy the `Generic` template seven times, renaming the copies:

```
{db2a5d8f-06e6-4007-aba6-af877d526ea6}
{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656}
{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}
{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78}
{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}
{CD0FC69B-71E2-46e5-9690-5BCD9F57AAB3}
{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8}
```

You also want to create four copies of the `OneeDrive` template and name the copies:

```
{DD61BD66-70E8-48dd-9655-65C5E1AAC2D1}
{672ECD7E-AF04-4399-875C-0290845B6247}
{71D642A9-F2B1-42cd-AD92-EB9300C7CC0A}
{51294DA1-D7B1-485b-9E9A-17CFFE33E187}
```

If you're doing this manually, you want to export the key with the two template values and then use a text editor to duplicate and rename the desired values in a `.reg` file, then merge the edited `.reg` file.

If you're comfortable with **PowerShell**, use this code:

```
$Defaults        = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults'

$Generic         = (gp $Defaults).'{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}'
$OneDriveGeneric = (gp $Defaults).'{4F01EBC5-2385-41f2-A28E-2C5C91FB56E0}'

-split @'
{db2a5d8f-06e6-4007-aba6-af877d526ea6}
{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656}
{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}
{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78}
{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}
{CD0FC69B-71E2-46e5-9690-5BCD9F57AAB3}
{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8}
'@ | ForEach {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $Defaults -Name $_ -Value $Generic
}

-split @'
{DD61BD66-70E8-48dd-9655-65C5E1AAC2D1}
{672ECD7E-AF04-4399-875C-0290845B6247}
{71D642A9-F2B1-42cd-AD92-EB9300C7CC0A}
{51294DA1-D7B1-485b-9E9A-17CFFE33E187}
'@ | ForEach {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $Defaults -Name $_ -Value $OneDriveGeneric
}
```

Regardless of how you copy the values, the end result in the registry should look like this:

[image]

6. Restart the system.

---

Will address SearchResults and Libraries in an edit.

Comment: Thank you for this. One note though: while the downloads folder view in the explorer is fixed, its view in dialogs (e.g., downloading and/or uploading something and it asks for a location) remain grouped and sorted by date. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The common dialogs should be following the new default -- they are here ( Because updates can change behavior at any time, I implememetned all the mods I suggested on my machine before posting and they're still in effect ). To satisfy my curiosity, please see if the dialog view is different when  you navigate to `Downloads`  via a differnt namespace path than the one that displayed the grouped view. So if `This PC\Downloads` was grouped, try  `This PC\C:\Users\<UserProfile>\Downloads` or `shell:UsersFilesFolder\Downloads`. Use **Notepad**'s `Open` dialog to ensure you're using common dialogs.

Comment: Assuming the above test went well, modifying the view within the dialog (right-click in dialog background to access `Sort by` and `Group by`) before dismissing it should be sufficient. If not, open `regedit` and search under `HKCU\...\Bags`  for subkeys named `{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}`. If any of the found keys are *subkeys* of `ComDlg` or 'ComDlgLegacy' *and* contain a `GroupView` value of `0xffffffff`, delete the entire subkey. Sign out, log back in, and test.

Comment: Sorry, I believe I forgot to restart back then. Having followed your steps again with the mentioned restarts, I now consistently find that the `Downloads` folder is not affected by this at all - it's still grouping and sorting by date, even in the explorer. As of right now, the steps I tried brought me closer to my goal than yours. Perhaps something has changed in Win11, I'm not sure.